# Difference between attributes and base_attributes in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've seen several models define a static method

```
self.base_attributes
 {
    :object => []
 }
end
```

and some other models define the static method

```
self.attributes
  @@attributes = {}
end
```

What exactly is the difference between attributes and base attributes?

Comment: Can you point to some examples in the source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in your example without knowing more about the code, the `self.attributes` method is using a class variable (`@@attributes`), which means that you could add more attributes to it at run time.

Where as your `base_attributes` is hard coded. I suspect you're seeing something like:

`base_attributes.merge(attributes)` which is a way of defining default values perhaps.